# Off road tyre and rim for Audi A3 quattro

Tags: tires

I'm plaaning a "loop" of Australia in an Audi A3 quattro, which I estimate at about 15,000 kilometers total. The majority will be on sealed roads but I expect the more interesting aspects of the drive to be on unsealed roads, likely 100-200km off the sealed highway. I appreciate a 4WD is probably the 'ideal' vehicle but I'm not interested in buying one specifically for this trip.

In the past, I've done long multi-thousand km trips and thought that I just needed road tyres. However a couple of times I've nearly been stuck just travelling a small distance offroad. If there has been heavy rainfall (common in Northern Australia), a soil with a lot of clay looks like regular dirt but gets very slippery & muddy. I figure an off-road tyre may offer better puncture resistance as well.

So I'm seeking an off-road tyre for a 2011 A3 quattro. The current rim is a 17 inch. I figure I will need to drop to a 16-inch rim to find a more off-road tyre i.e. a tyre profile like 215/65R16.

So (I believe) my questions are essentially:

- What 16-inch rim will replace the Audi 17-inch and keep the same offset?
- What off-road tyre sizes will generally fit the above rim? I imagine that manufacturers aim for specific sizes for offroad tyres (happy to have specific tyres nominated)

Update:

Trying to answer my question by working backwards, a Michelin LTX Force can be had at 215/65R16. A 215 tyre width would dictate a rim width of either 7 or 7.5 inches according to https://www.tyresizecalculator.com/charts/tire-width-for-a-wheel-rim-size-chart. So for that tyre, a 16inch rim of 7/7.5 inch width with the same offset and pattern would fit.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on what kind of rim/tire to buy? Or what sizes/types you'd need to suit the off-roading?

Comment: I've updated to some specific questions. Got a bit carried away with the preamble.

Comment: I'm afraid this is looking more and more like a shopping question, which would be off-topic.

Comment: I'm tryiing to avoid a shopping question of course. I need to determine what offroad tire sizes are available in order to determine what wheel rim spec i can fit. I suppose I can just go and ask a vendor/tyre fitter.

Comment: The Audi Quattro won several rallies on varied surfaces - check out what they used...

Comment: @SolarMike The OP has an A3 with a quattro system fitted, not the actual Quattro model (have edited the title to remove the confusion)

Comment: @motosubatsu I know, but they chose good tyres so that may give the OP a start with this "shopping" question...

Comment: @SolarMike I may be taking this too literally but.. I'm still not seeing how competition rally tires from over 30 years ago are particularly useful.

Comment: @timbo your thinking in the "update" section is misguided.. you can't start from "I want this tire size" and work backwards. As stated in my answer the diameter of a 215/65R16 tire is *significantly* greater than that of what you currently have and you could be buying trouble for yourself doing that. Also offset is rim-width dependent, not tires - so if you go for a a 7J or 7.5J rim (either should fit) then the offset would need to be  ET51 and ET56 respectively.

Comment: @motosubatsu according to a tire site, the options of 16" and 17" are available for the sportback (quattro is only listed with the engine options...) and the sizes shown are 205/50 R17, 225/45 R17 and, interestingly 205/55 R16 in 91W and 91H varieties...

Comment: @SolarMike yeah quattro/non-quattro doesn't effect which wheels fit on those nor does body style (the sportback is basically a small estate)  - the determining factor is the brakes, which is why you can't fit 16" to the 3.2 or the S3. 205/55R15  matches with what I know - I just can't see 215/65R16 working, especially on rougher terrain it'll be fouling on the arches left right and center.

Answer (score 2):

A 2011 A3 is on the 8P platform, for a 16" rim it should be 6.5Jx16 ET50 and the tire size is 205/55R16, a 215/65R16 tire is going to add 2" to the total diameter (vs the standard 225/45R17 tires that will be on the existing 17" rims, 2.5" extra over the 205/55R16) which is quite a lot and I'd be very concerned about it fouling on the arches, particularly on the sort of terrain you describe. And of course it will throw the speedometer and odometer accuracy out in the process.

You don't mention the variant you have but the 16" should be fine for pretty much all of them barring the 3.2FSI or the S3 (16" won't fit over the brakes on those - you have to be 17" and up)

**PS:** When shopping for rims you'll want to consider the **strength** of the wheels as well - budget alloys may seem attractive from a cost perspective but could soon be a false economy if they can't take the hits. If cost is a concern steel wheels might be a better bet.

Comment: Great answer! Gives me some good info on rim and appropriate tire size. Your comment about steel wheels re strength is very pertinent. This video from a rally school mentions that entry level rally drivers use steel wheels - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gIVD1mzM9I  And it seems that Stock level rallycross drivers will simply use snow tires - https://medium.com/@JimRowland/where-to-buy-rallycross-tires-b6d0a93d9e20. So my current thinking is: snow tires on steel rims.